# Web-To-Case Link To Existing Case

Tags: web2case

I have a requirement where an internal system is using web-to-case to create new cases when fraud alerts occur.  However, there could be multiple fraud alerts per client and we do not want a separate case for each, we want the alerts for the same client to be grouped in any existing open case (there will only be 1 fraud case open at a time).  Is this possible using web-to-case?  If not, does anyone know how we can accomplish this?

Just to elaborate a bit, and example of what might happen:

***This info would really only need to be entered to SFDC once.***

Client:  XYZ Company
Date of Fraud:  1/1/2016 12:00:00
Disabled:  TRUE (disable client)
Billing Card:  xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx
Billing State:  NY
Status:  Open

***This info would need to be appended to an open case, perhaps through a related list?***

Detection:  Picklist
Rule:  Picklist
Identifier: String

Comment: even i am also searching for the solution like this.But in my case i'm using workflow field update based on case comments i'm closing the case automatically. @J. Neilan

Comment: It would seem that you "should" be able to run a check for an existing case of the same type as part of your assignment rules. If one is found, then add or update the existing case via workflow, process builder or a trigger.

Comment: @crmprogdev -- When you say "add or update my existing" do you mean associate it as a related case or append data to the existing case?  I was thinking that I might have to create a custom object off cases to capture the additions.  I've updated my original post to explain more detail.

Comment: I was thinking in terms of adding it to the case notes for the existing open case or as you say, append it, depending on what terminology works for you and your workflow. If you're using the email object, I believe you'd need a trigger or class to insert it into the existing thread.

Comment: There's a feature in Case SObject allowing for a hierarchy of Cases (see field `ParentId`) and hence a before insert trigger could assign Case 2,3,4 to parent Case 1.

Comment: @crmprogdev -- Thanks.  Ideally, it would be as a separate related list with just a few fields.  It would not be an email thread.


cropredy -- I thought about the linked Cases route, but there could potentially be quite a few of these per Account so I thought that might get a bit unruly.

In either case, could anyone point me to potentially some sample code on how to go about adding as a related list?

Comment: Unless you're using a custom page, adding that should be point and click functionality.

Comment: @crmprogdev -- Not sure what you mean?  I can do it without Apex?

Comment: Yes, I'd expect you to be able to do it through a combination of assignment rules and workflow that checks for the duplicates when the case is created/assigned and takes action accordingly. That's all pretty much point and click isn't it?

Comment: @crmprogdev -- Possibly.  I'll give it a shot.  Thanks for the direction!

Comment: Another option is a custom inbound email handler to avoid having to work against the standard behaviour. See here https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_To_Email_Services_on_Force.com